# How to set proxy for android ethernet connection?

Tags: android, proxy, ethernet, android-networking, android-settings

Is it possible somehow, in a setting, configuration or code to set a proxy for an ethernet connection on Android 4.*? My app is using the Webview so setting the proxy in the os should do the job for me. But I can only find settings to set proxy for wifi, not ethernet connections.

Comment: Does your device have a Ethernet port?

Comment: @nyarlathotep77 Yes it does have an ethernet port. Its a device similar to odroid.